# Add custom HTML to Wordpress WP-Members form

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a registration/login form which was created with WP-Members plugin on Wordpress. I'd like to add the text `"Our customers enjoy receiving special offers..."` and `"Your personal data will be used..."` to be included in the form as custom HTML text which can then be translated via Polylang.

[image]

Its currently set up as a value in the Newsletter radio button. See image below:

[image]

If I can't add those as custom HTML in the backend is there a way I can add the text to string translations in Polylang?

thanks

Comment: You need to find php page control the form and add some function to echo text with lang selected.

Comment: Do you have an example or know of an example of the code? I'm not a coder so new to this

Comment: Here is a guide: [LINK](https://www.butlerblog.com/2010/09/27/adding-custom-fields-in-wp-members/)

Comment: Ok great I'll have a look, thank you

Comment: I've looked at that page and there doesn't seem to be a file called wp-members-install.php or a function called $wpmem_fields_options_arr. Could you let me know if these have changed and called something else

Comment: This is official wiki of WP members : [LINK](https://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/docs/getting-started/)